# Entity Framework - Including Collections on Derived from Base DBSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

The main question I'm asking is:

> *Is there a way to keep a DbSet based off the base class and still support eager loading for a Derived object in a single retrieve method that only requires an Id?  The answer may be that you can't.  I'm just hoping I'm overlooking something.*

Consider the following situation:

```
//Models
public class Base {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string BaseProp {get;set;}
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public string DerivedProp {get;set;}
}

//Context
DbSet<Base> Bases {get;set;}

//Saving
public void Save(Base obj){
    // Adding only for brevity
    context.Bases.Add(obj)
    context.SaveChanges();
}

//Retrieval
public Base Retrieve(int id){
    return context.Bases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

EF6 is smart enough to know when Base objects are actually Derived objects and populate the additional fields on save as well as retrieve the objects as Derived objects.

However, if I change the derived class to be:

```
public class Derived : Base {
    public string DerivedProp {get;set;}
    public ICollection<SomeLookup> Lookup {get; set;}  // Creates junction table with Id/LookupId as columns
}
```

I can still save (and it populates the junction table beautifully with the selected lookups), but I no longer can retrieve the full object in my Base DbSet because I can't change it to have an eager include on a collection that Base doesn't know exists.

I could virtualize the collection so it will lazy load when the mapping occurs down the line, but I'm wondering, and this is the root question:

---

**Update:** Essentially all I want to know is, if I only have an Id to work with for my retrieve, the following wont work, but is there something like it that will?

```
context.Bases.Include(x => ((Derived)x).Lookup).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
```

The use case would be that I have a list page.  That page doesn't need to care what types it is because it only has the base properties on it.  Should I go into one of the edit pages, the server only gets passed the Id.

I'll settle for the lazy load if that's the only way as that will happen when I build the DTO after the retrieve, but I was wondering if there was some EF configuration that I don't know about for modelBuilder or a way to write a project query that I haven't found yet that allows an Eager Load for that Derived Lookup collection?

**Update 2:** Accepted answer based on him letting me know I can't do what I was hoping.  Also found [this on the EF uservoice](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-eager-loading-for-properties-of-derived-classes).

Comment: Could you show code that get data from database? What is the usecase when you get base dbset and need to have derived navigation properties included?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I did an update to the question.  It's quite possible allowing the lazy load is fine and I'm just premature optimizing here for no reason (who knows, the resulting SQL could be worse).  I'm more just curious if something like this can actually work because I was even surprised the Base & Derived stuff worked as well as it did out of the box.

Comment: Do you know what deriver type is for current id? If yes, you can use generic Set<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially all I want to know is, if I only have an Id to work with for my retrieve, the following wont work, but is there something like it that will?

If your derived objects use some type of Entity Framework Inheritence; [Mapping the Table-Per-Type (TPT) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5) or [Mapping the Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4) or [Mapping the Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4).

Then *Yes*,

```
db.Bases
  .OfType<Derived>()
  .Include(d => d.Lookup)
  .Where(d => d.Id = someId)
  .ToList();
```

Otherwise *No*, it will not.

Comment: I spent a bit of time fiddling with those and none seemed to fit.  Odd because I don't think I'm doing anything special so would have thought I would have been the default.  The TypeOf<Derived> just ended up returning nulls when the Id was a for just a Base.  That said, appreciate the insight as it looks like it isn't quite possible for what I'm looking for as I also found this: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-eager-loading-for-properties-of-derived-classes

Comment: So you are using one of those supported Inheritance types?

Comment: I think I have a bit of a cross going on.  I have TPH with some generic base properties, but then TPT for the real type differences of classes that are not abstract.  The merging of styles still lets me do very simple entity linq querying, just missing this one bit for derived includes which apparently isn't supported.  Much appreciate the insight.

Comment: The LINQ extention method is `OfType<>` not `TypeOf<>` as indicated. I requested an edit but in case it is never approved please note.